# Excel formula to create a unique list produces a 0 at the bottom that I cannot remove

Tags: excel

Here's my situation

Goal: create a unique list in sheet2 based on a list with duplicates in sheet1.

What I've tried: ={IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$2:B2,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100),0)),"")}

The issue: the formula produces the list I'm looking for, however it produces a 0 at the end of the list (e.g. B3 through B25 is correct but cell B26 has a 0). The problem is I can't figure out how to delete it. I've tried an if(0,"") statement and that doesn't work. Note, my list in Sheet1 only has about 25 total entries, however I want the formula to read to B100 to account for additional material. I did however try the formula ending exactly where my list ends and that does not produce a zero.

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the blank cell at row 26 will satisfy the equation as unique:

You can add a another criterion:

```
IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100,MATCH(1,(COUNTIF($B$2:B2,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100)=0)*(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100<>""),0)),"")
```

This is an array formula and needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Another method would be to make the reference data set dynamic:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,MATCH("ZZZ",Sheet1!$B:$B)),MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$2:B2,Sheet1!$B$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,MATCH("ZZZ",Sheet1!$B:$B))),0)),"")
```

This will set the referenced data to the extents, and as new data is added it will automatically grow or shrink and thus never refer to a blank cell.

Use the above if the data on sheet 1 is Text if it is numbers replace both `"ZZZ"` with `1E+99`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was really helpful. One quick question: one of my sheets only has two rows, a header and one line of data. The formula does not work for this sheet. What's the reason for that?

Comment: It's ridiculous that a blank counts as a unique value of zero in the first place.